# Регистронезависимый поиск с использованием bootstrap-typeahead.min.js

Tags: php, javascript, плагин

Здравствуйте Всем!

Проблема:

Н-р: В базе хранится название записи "Поисковый запрос" и "поисковый запрос"

Когда я ввожу в input запрос например, только первую букву "п" она вернет оба результата http://screencast.com/t/gYlGqDjEJE Это правильно,
потом ввожу следующую букву и результат уже другой http://screencast.com/t/LFmZbqfFg Это не правильно, она должна была вернуть оба результата.

код отправки и приема дпнных js (typeahead)

```
    $('#q').typeahead({
    matcher: function(result){
        return result;
    },
    source: function (query, process) {
        var results = [];
        allres = {};
        var $tid = $('#tid').val();
        // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
        return $.post('ajax/search.php', {a: "search", tip: $tid, q: query}, function (data) {
            // Loop through and push to the array
            $.each(data.results, function (i, res) {
                allres[res.label] = res;
                results.push(res.label);
            });
            // Process the details
            process(results);
            var length_q = $('#q').length;
            if (length_q > 0) {
                if (results == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("inner_empty").innerHTML = "Ничего не найдено!";
                    $("#inner_empty").addClass("empty_show");
                }else{
                    $("#inner_empty").removeClass("empty_show");
                }
            }
        });
    },
    updater: function (item) {

        var selecteID = allres[item].id;
        var selTid = allres[item].tid;
        var $gourl = "";
        //alert(selTid);
        if (parseInt(selTid) === 1) {
            $gourl = 'catalog-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else if (parseInt(selTid) === 2) {
            $gourl = 'specialist-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else if (parseInt(selTid) === 3) {
            $gourl = 'blog-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else if (parseInt(selTid) === 4) {
            $gourl = 'advert-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else if (parseInt(selTid) === 5) {
            $gourl = 'poster-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else if (parseInt(selTid) === 6) {
            $gourl = 'catalog-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else if (parseInt(selTid) === 7) {
            $gourl = 'article-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        } else {
            $gourl = 'author-detail.php?id=' + selecteID;
        }
        window.location.href = $gourl;
        return item;
    }
});
```

sql

```
$sql = "(SELECT id, type, name as title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "objects WHERE uname LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR name LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, type, name as title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "specialist WHERE uname LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR name LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, type, title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "blogs WHERE uname LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, type, title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "posters WHERE uname LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, type, name as title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "adverts WHERE uname LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR name LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, type, title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "authors WHERE title LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, type, title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "articles WHERE uname LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT user_id as id, type, user_name as title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "users WHERE user_name LIKE '%" . $q . "%')
        UNION
        (SELECT id, parent_name as type, title FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "about WHERE title LIKE '%" . $q . "%')";

        $resq = $db->query($sql);
        foreach ($resq as $rw) {
            $res        = new Results();
            $res->id    = $rw["id"];
            $res->label = $rw["title"];
            $res->tid   = $rw['type'];
            array_push($arrRes, $res);
        }
```

в array_push($arrRes, $res); помещается ответ

после обработки php кодом, результат помещается в js result
http://screencast.com/t/uAS8xTsXf2Zb

В *недоумении* по сути должно было вывести результат "Для поиска" и т.п. и т.д. а вышло только это!

Хотя когда вставляю сам sql в базу нормально все выводит.

после typehead что то творит и выдает данные определенного регистра, выбрасывая все что за пределами ограничения.

---

#### На локалке нормально работает а на хосте нет

---

Заранее Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: как тяжело читать со скринов код, привидите код php где запрашиваеться результат с бд и где обрабатываеться после запроса.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Обновил вопрос

Comment: тут я скланяюсь к php а точнее проверьте корректна ли кодировка или нет и насколько я понимаю like регистрозависимый. Если это mysql мой вам совет заюзать sphinx так как меньше тягать данных из б.д. придёться. да и быстрее он в разы и точнее выборка.

Comment: Абсолютно правы! проблема была в кодировке -_- . Исправил. Спасибо!